# How do you find the time taken to boot?

Tags: linux, time, boot

I am not referring to holding a stop watch when the boot takes place.

But is there a way to find the time taken for the complete boot operation in Linux/Windows?

Comment: Well you need to define "complete boot operation".

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to do it by yourself, but you can always use `dmesg` and parse the timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

[Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) can give you a lot of information about the boot process of a Linux system (including a graphical representation).

A more up-to-date version (called [bootchart2](https://github.com/mmeeks/bootchart/)) is on GitHub.